# How to use GoogleMaps in local Swift Package?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios, swift-package-manager, apple-appclips

I'm trying to build an iOS Application which provides AppClips. This means I need to put my code into modules so that the AppClip can reuse some of the code from the main application. The reusable part is using GoogleMaps and that SDK is not yet available via SPM. There is a third-party-fork which makes it SPM-compatible and it kind of works, but it wont let me upload the build because the GoogleMaps SDK gets imported/linked multiple times. Also there is some kind of error stating that it is not "inside the framework folder".

Can anyone provide a solution as to how to use GoogleMaps inside of a local Swift Package? I'm even fine with some kind of hack, because I still hope Google will provide SPM support soon.

So is there a way to use cocoapods or carthage pods or whatever inside a local Swift Package?